# importing 'games' and window closes

Tags: python, import

I am attempting to make a program that opens up other programs (games that i have made previously) and the window closes instantly.

```
#Program that runs game i have made
import subprocess

choice = input("What would you like to do? \nGuess my number game (1) \nCalorie counter (2) \nWord jumble game (3) \nInsert your decision here - ")

while choice == "1":
    print("Let us begin")
    def start_guess_my_number():   
        subprocess.call(['python', 'Guess my number game2.py'])
    start_guess_my_number() 
    choice = input("What would you like to do now? 1 2 or 3 ? - ")
while choice == "2":
    print("Let us begin")
    def start_calorie_counter():
        subprocess.call(['python', 'Calorie counter.py'])
    start_calorie_counter()
    choice = input("What would you like to do now? 1 2 or 3 ? - ")
while choice == "3":
    print("Let us begin")
    def start_guess_my_number():
        subprocess.call(['python', 'Word jumble game.py'])
    start_guess_my_number()
    choice = input("What would you like to do now? 1 2 or 3 ? - ")
input("Press enter to exit")
```

note: I have made sure that the programs I am calling upon are working, and when opened in the black command window, they stay open, unlike when I open them via this program.

Comment: Use the terminal to run your program (python app.py), and you might see some output

Answer (score 4):

You had the following problems:

- You need to compare the input to an int, not a string
- You need to open the game in the right folder, by default the new process runs in the folder that contains the python executable.
- You were using while loops instead of if statements, your code would have been caught in an infinite loop.
- There was no way to get out of the main loop, you need a break statement to achieve that.

I also separated the code into functions.

```
#Program that runs a game I have made
import os
import subprocess


def play_game(name):
    print("Let us begin")
    subprocess.call(['python', os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))+os.path.sep+name])


choice = input("What would you like to do? \nGuess my number game (1) \nCalorie counter (2) \nWord jumble game (3) \nInsert your decision here - ")

while True:
    if choice == 1:
        play_game('Guess my number game2.py')
    elif choice == 2:
        play_game('Calorie counter.py')
    elif choice == 3:
        play_game('Word jumble game.py')
    else:
        break
    choice = input("What would you like to do now? 1 2 or 3 ? - ")
print("Goodbye")
```